# Algorithm to count the number of connected elements for each element in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I am looking for way to find the number of connected (neighboring) elements in a matrix. 
I'm given a 2D-array of objects where each object may have a flag set. If the flag is set I need to count the number of neighbours that have the flag set aswell. For each neighbour the process is repeated.

See the image for a visualization of the problem:
[image: visualization]

I guess this is a rather common problem. What is it's name so I can do my own research?

Comment: Not sure, hence the comment, but I think that a recursive method which is able to backtrack should be able to do what you need, thus I think that backtracking might be the topic you are after.

Comment: You're looking for connected components in the graph of cells with the flag set. Both depth and breadth first search can be used to find them in linear time.

Comment: can you record every time you add an element in the matrix or do you have to calcul after being given a specific one?

Comment: I am given a finished matrix created in a blackbox.

Comment: You can look at image segmentation algorithms like the Watershed algorithm or other "region growing" algorithms

Comment: @NiklasB. Can you provide references on the DFS and BFS approaches you are thinking of ?

Comment: This is commonly called connected components labeling (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling). Have a look at "A linear-time component-labeling algorithm using contour tracing technique".

Comment: @YvesDaoust DFS is described in the answer below. BFS would use an explicity queue instead of the explicit recursion stack, but otherwise work equivalently

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be done with **[flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)**, which is a variant of [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). This assume your matrix is actually a graph, where each cell is a node, and there is an edge between two adjacent cells.

a possible pseudocode could be:

```
DFS(v,visited):
   if v is not set: 
       return []
   else:
        nodes = [v]
        for each neighbor u of v:
            if u is not in visited:
                  visited.add(u)
                  nodes.addAll(DFS(u,visited))
        return nodes
```

If you start from some point `v`, it will return t list containing all nodes connected to `v` (including `v` itself), and you can easily set their "value" as `size(nodes)`.

The following pseudo code will mark ALL nodes with the size of their "cluster":

```
markAll(V): //V is the set of all cells in the matrix
    visited = [] //a hash set is probably best here
    while (V is not empty):
       choose random v from V
       visited.add(v)
       nodes = DFS(v,visited)
       for each u in nodes:
            value(u) = size(nodes)
       V = V \ nodes //set substraction
```

Complexity of this approach will be `O(|V|) = O(n*m)` - so linear in the size of the matrix (which is n*m)

Answer (score 5):

How about utilizing the [Disjoint set or union-find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) data structure?

Basically:

Whenever a flag is added, or you notice that an element has a flag, scan that element's neighbours. As soon as you find an element therein with a flag, you cluster the elements together by having them point to the same parent element. Either directly or recursively.

Keep a tally of the element count for every cluster.

Comment: A nice solution that has the advantage over the flood fill approach of being (a feature not requested in the original question) an online algorithm.

Comment: Thank you too. I'll give it a try aswell.

Comment: This solution is better (in term of performance) than floodfill if the flag  set is dynamic (and can only be set, not unset), and worse (performance and programming time) if it's (flag) is defined once and is constant.